# In Presto is there a way to do a like on an in statement

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

In Presto how do i combine like in for example below.

```
select * from table where cloumn in like ('abc','xyz')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL language, `IN` is the collection of `OR` conditions. Example, **Col IN ('abc', 'xyz')** is equal to **(Col = 'abc' OR Col = 'xyz')**.

So, you can achieve this by

```
select * from table where column LIKE '%abc%' OR column LIKE '%xyz%'
```

Or you can use the below one if the values are many and from different table.

```
SELECT T1.* FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.column Like '%' + T2.Value_column_to_match +'%'
```